# How to define specific fixed position of background image (or image) and then attach element on defined place?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with one thing.
I have a map of world and I want to add functionality when a user clicks on one of the list elements (you can see 3 lists with different places on the image, for example, **Paris Air Show**) it would show me on the map. As you can see on image example 
Is it possible to do? It should work on different devices, but I have no idea how to create that.
[image: Example]

Comment: You need to map it out with a grid using javascript. This can be achieved using x and y coordinates of the map element. Create an object with the key as the place (*list-item*) and the x/y coords as the value. Then a call back function in a click event on the list-items to reference the object and get the coords, create an element to show and place it at those coords. You really should show some effort at accomplishing this before asking for assistance. Your question will get more negative hits without showing any code, just an FYI...

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will try to do that!

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that. Will try to do that. I've tried to find some information about that but there was no result for me.

Comment: You just need to take it in small pieces. First create a window event that will show you the coordinates of your mouse on a click within the map, click the cities to get the x and y coords, then you can build your object. Something like `places = [{ NewYork: { x: 221, y: 129, info: 'Info about New York event'  }, etc...` then you can reference the info in the object using `places[0][e.target.dataset.place]['x']` where `e.target.dataset.place` represents dataset attribute with `NewYork` as it value. When you click on the list-items that has that datasets attribute value.

Comment: You will have issues with smaller devices however, making that dynamic would likely mean writing a static map and callback for each media query device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help. 
Here is a good solution, which works for me. 
So I've created a map with areas and on those areas, I put coordinates of places and this map is attached to the image. Then I calculate a place using `map.getBoundingClientRect()`